# Green’s reciprocity theorem

Tags: electrostatics, charge

I've been reading about the [Green’s reciprocity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_%28electromagnetism%29) lately from [this page](http://www.physicspages.com/2012/04/02/greens-reciprocity-theorem/) (link now dead; page available at the [Wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20170214070242/http://www.physicspages.com/2012/04/02/greens-reciprocity-theorem/)) and I have some questions regarding one problem solved on this site (example 3)... Using all the notations used by the author, I agree that from Gauss's applied outside the sphere with radius b we have :
$$ Q_a+Q_b=-q$$
 But , if we consider calculating the potential inside the sphere with radius a, I end up with this formula:
$$ \frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r}+\frac{Q_a}{4\pi \epsilon_0 a}+\frac{Q_b}{4\pi \epsilon_0 b}=V_a=0 $$

Which gives the wanted result without applying the reciprocity theorem.Does this mean that the Green’s reciprocity theorem is equivalent to the formula above?

Comment: -1 It is not helpful to base a question (or answer) on information provided in a link. If as here the information is essential to understanding your question, you need to reproduce or at least summarise it here.

Answer (score 1):

The link in your question is dead but I'm assuming you are referring to problem 3.44 from Griffiths E&M?

Two concentric spherical conducting shells (radii $a$ and $b$) are grounded, and a point charge $q$ is place between them (at radius $r$). Find the induced charge on each sphere.

You say by considering the potentials inside the sphere with radius $a$ you get:

$$
\frac{q}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r}+\frac{Q_a}{4\pi \epsilon_0 a}+\frac{Q_b}{4\pi \epsilon_0 b}=V_a=0
$$

Where exactly inside sphere $a$ are you talking about, such that you get this formula? I assume at the center given the values you chose for distance. It looks like you are assuming

$$V(r)=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}$$

where $r$ is the distance from the origin. However, this is the formula for the electric potential caused by a point charge. The contributions to the potential from spheres $a$ and $b$ cannot (in general) be treated as point charges since you're looking from inside the sphere and the charge distribution across the surface of the spheres will not be uniform (because charge $q$ breaks the symmetry).

Here you have more or less gotten lucky that it works to treat all the charge induced on the spheres as point charges such that the two points of induced charge and $q$ all lie along a line. This is not obvious, and you would need to prove it or find an existing theorem to use before your method would be rigorous. Or for a simple rigorous derivation for the induced charges, you could use Green's reciprocity theorem :)

Comment: OP's link is available at the Wayback Machine [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20170214070242/http://www.physicspages.com/2012/04/02/greens-reciprocity-theorem/).